# Multiple PHP IF conditions not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to make sure the GET string is set in the URL and that it's value is an integer, but I can't get this to work.

```
if (isset($_GET['allusers']) && is_int($_GET['allusers'])) {

    echo "works";

}
```

Am I doing something wrong with my parentheses?

Comment: Values in `$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc. are either strings or arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `$_GET` variable can't be an integer. It'll always be a string.

To test is it's a numeric string, use [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php):

```
if ( isset($_GET['allusers']) && is_numeric($_GET['allusers']) )
{
    echo "works";
}
```

Comment: Note that is_numeric allows floating-point values as well (0.5, 5e10 and so on).

Answer (score 0):

In your code

```
isset($_GET['allusers'])
```

will be evaluated to be true but 
is_int($_GET['allusers']) will not as the value of $_GET is a string not int you can modify your code as

```
if (isset($_GET['allusers']) && is_int(intval($_GET['allusers']))) {

    echo "works";

}
```

This will work

Comment: `intval` will *always*  return an integer (`0` on error is also an integer) so the `is_int` check is not needed. Note that the behaviour may be unexpected on strings such as `42helloworld`.

Comment: `is_int(intval(...))` will *always* evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ctype_digit`](http://php.net/ctype_digit) if you are expecting only non-negative integers. This will give the best result in those cases since it allows *only* the numbers `0-9`.

Note that [`is_numeric`](http://php.net/is_numeric) will return `true` for strings which can be converted to integers, both negatives and floats. A few examples of what `is_numeric` will consider to be `true`:

- `0xF5` (hexadecimal)
- `-.0e-000` (a strange way of expressing `0.0`)
- `-0.4`

Answer (score -1):

[is_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) returns `false` on a string, which is what a GET variable will be.

```
var_dump(is_int("23"));
bool(false)
```

You should be using [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) instad.